# Custom user links

Tags: sharepoint-online, following

I am using sharepoint online.

I'm trying to create a webapp that is unique for each employee in my company that will appear on the homepage of the intranet.

It will be a list of documents or pages that they find useful. It's sort of like a custom quick link list that they can add and remove from.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the out of the box functionality when you hit the SharePoint tile in the waffle. This is effectively what you're attempting to recreate. You can add `Featured Links` while your users can add their own via Following sites.

Comment: Sorry, 'hit the SharePoint tile in the waffle'?

Comment: In the waffle (upper left hand menu) in Office 365 there is a tile named SharePoint. That'll take you to the page I'm referring to.